# Harmonic polymonials approximating function

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-functions

Can we approximate $f(x)=-x_1^2/2$ defined in the unit cube of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by a sequence of harmonic polynomials?

We can find a compact subset $K$  of the unit cube such that it has empty interior, the complement of it in the unit cube has measure as small as you want and the complement of it in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, so by Mergelyan's theorem, we can find a sequence of polynomials approximating $f$ uniformly in $K$. But how we find a sequence of harmonic polynomials approximating $f$ uniformly? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The uniform limit of harmonic functions is also harmonic, so...

Comment: So we cannot do that? Since f is not harmonic?